# Shell regex to end of line

Tags: regex, shell

I have a file like this little example:

```
# ...
# mode=dev
# ...
```

Somewhere in this file there is a "variable" within a comment. And i would like to get the value with regex in a Shell script.

My code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
conf=$(<"/etc/test.conf") # Get the file content
regex='mode=(.*)$' # Set a regex
if [[ $conf =~ $regex ]]; then # Search for the regex in the file
    # We found it, so ...
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" # ... here is the value
fi
```

My big problem is, that it will not find the value :(
I tried a lot of different regex expressions and tested them with https://regex101.com/ , but it seems, that the Shell regex interprator is different from `pcre` and `python`.

My best solution was to find the `mode=` and **everything** after it. So is there a way to get only the value? The start is easy ... find `mode=`. But how do I say the shell regex to get everything behind `mode=` **until** the next linebreak? and **not beyond** this linebreak?
Something with `\n` (unix linebreak) and `$` (end of string) did not work for me :(

Thanks for the help,
greetings

Comment: try `mode=[^\n]+` where `[^\n]` matches anything that _isn't_ a new line. Also, do you have to set modifiers in [tag:Shell] ?

Comment: I already tried this and when I do this, he takes a few lines. Is there maybe another linebreak then `\n`?

Comment: could be a carriage return. try `mode=[^\r\n]` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to get your match:

```
conf=$(<"/etc/test.conf")
regex=$'mode=([^\n]*)'
[[ $conf =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

**Output:**

```
dev
```

Regex `$'mode=([^\n]*)'` will match literal text `mode=` followed by 0 or more of any character that is not `\n`.

Comment: this matches the literal character `n` meaning 0 or more of any character that is not an n

Comment: Make sure to use bash