# match to end of line in bash regex with =~

Tags: regex, bash, match

I am trying to use bash regex match to parse a line out of a multi-line string. Why does the following not work?

```
if [[ $qout =~ ${q}[^\n]* ]] ; then
```

It matches up to the letter `n`. I tried using `\\n` or even `\\\n`, but nothing worked.

`$qout` contains:

```
unrouted    0   0   running
dead-letter 0   0   running
```

`$q` contains `unrouted`.

`${BASH_REMATCH[0]` evaluates to:

```
unrouted    0   0   ru
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't have to use bash, a more featureful scripting language may help you get this done!

Comment: @ti7, bash has all the features needed for this task.

Comment: `if [[ $qout =~ ${q}[^$'\n']* ]] ; then`

Answer (score 7):

`[\n]` doesn't match a newline -- it matches either a literal backslash, or an `n`. If you run `nl=$'\n'` and then use `$nl` is your regex, things will work as-intended.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
qout='unrouted    0   0   running
dead-letter 0   0   running'

q=unrouted

nl=$'\n'
if [[ $qout =~ ${q}[^$nl]*[$nl] ]]; then
  declare -p BASH_REMATCH
else
  echo "No match found" >&2
fi
```

...emits as output:

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]=$'unrouted    0   0   running\n')
```

Comment: Bash will even use `$q[^$'\n']+` as the regex. I hadn't tried a character literal in a list before...

Comment: No need for a character class: `a=$'hello\nworld'; [[ $a =~ (.*)$'\n'(.*) ]]; typeset -p BASH_REMATCH` → `declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]=$'hello\nworld' [1]="hello" [2]="world")`

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- from a multi-line variable (`qout`) extract a line that contains a pattern (`q`)
- extract from the pattern (`q`) to the end of the line (to be captured in `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`)

A slight modification to the multi-line variable:

```
$ echo ${qout)
this is unrouted    0   0   running
dead-letter    0   0   running
```

**NOTE**: I added the 'this is' prefix to first line so we can verify where the parsing starts.

One idea - borrowing from this answer ([shell regex to end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32952690/7366100)):

```
$ sfx=$'[^\n]*'                  # match up to first newline (`\n`) character;
                                 # must use single quotes;
                                 # double quotes will cause the `\n` to be evaluated as the character `n`

$ [[ $qout =~ ${q}${sfx} ]] && echo 'match'
match
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
unrouted    0   0   running
```

FWIW, wrapping the test/`echo` in a `set -/+ xv` shows:

```
$ [[ $qout =~ ${q}${sfx} ]] && echo 'match'
+ [[ this is unrouted    0   0   running
dead-letter    0   0   running =~ unrouted[^
]* ]]
+ echo match
match
```

---

Adding @David C. Rankin's comment to the mix (placing the `\n` directly in the regex):

```
$ [[ $qout =~ ${q}[^$'\n']* ]] && echo 'match'
match
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
unrouted    0   0   running
```

**NOTE**: I can remove this if David wants to post his own answer.